# How can I solve this PDE using Fourier Transformation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    u_t=u_{xx}+4u+x^2-2t-4x^2t+2\cos^2(x),  x\in (0,\pi) \\
    u(x,0)=0 \\
    u_x(0,t)=0 \\
    u_x(\pi ,t)=2\pi t 
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I've asked about that PDE [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120073/how-should-i-solve-u-t-u-xx4ux2-2t-4x2t2-cos2x-if-one-of-its-condit), and got a solution but without using the Fourier Transformation

But we should solve this with the help of the Fourier Transformation

So how should I do it? Because we only did that for

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    u_t=a^2u_{xx},  x\in (0,l) \\
    u(x,0)=... \\
    u_x(0,t)=... \\
    u_x(l ,t)=... 
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

But we cannot apply it to the PDE given because it's not a heat equation in the first place

Comment: At first sight, I think you can use Fourier series, not Fourier transforms

Comment: We called it "Fourier method of separation of variables for initial-boundary problems" and "Fourier transform", something like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180768/using-fourier-transforms-to-solve-pde but with the exception that we assume that our u is u=v+w, so we get two systems of differential equations which we solve with the Fourier method